# About docker compose document version and docker compose package version installed

Tags: docker-compose

With the AI help I've created the following files:

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "3.8"

env_file:
  - ./env/global.env

services:
  db_migration:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${GLOBAL_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${GLOBAL_USER}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${GLOBAL_DB}
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - "./db/:/tmp/db"
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -e
      - -c
      - >
        sleep 4 && cd /tmp &&
        psql -h localhost -U postgres -f db/schema.sql -f db/data.sql

  postgraphile:
    image: graphile/postgraphile:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - db_migration
    environment:
      PGPASSWORD: ${GLOBAL_PASSWORD}
      PGUSER: ${GLOBAL_USER}
      PGDATABASE: ${GLOBAL_DB}
      PGHOST: ${GLOBAL_HOST}
    command:
      [
        "--enhance-graphiql",
        "--allow-explain",
        "--port",
        "5000",
        "--schema",
        "public",
        "--watch",
      ]
```

**global.env**

```
GLOBAL_PASSWORD=postgres
GLOBAL_USER=postgres
GLOBAL_DB=postgres
GLOBAL_HOST=local
```

When trying to run it I get these warnings:

```
WARN[0000] The "GLOBAL_PASSWORD" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "GLOBAL_USER" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "GLOBAL_DB" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "GLOBAL_PASSWORD" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "GLOBAL_USER" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "GLOBAL_DB" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "GLOBAL_HOST" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
validating /.../docker-compose.yml: (root) Additional property env_file is not allowed
```

According to AI this is because:

> Therefore, it is important to ensure that the version of Docker
> Compose on your system is equal to or greater than the version
> specified in the docker-compose.yml file.

Info:

- OS: EndeavourOS Linux x86_64
- Kernel: 6.3.3-zen1-1-zen
- Docker: 24.0.0, build 98fdcd769b
- Docker Compose: 2.18.1

So AI suggests to use for 2.14 for my Docker Compose document with certain changes.

In this point I'm confused because the latest version of docker compose is [2.18.1](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases), several sites use 3.18 for Docker Compose document, so I don't think package version and document version need to be the same version.

any help?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Keep in mind that AI generated questions are off-topic

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
env_file:
  - ./env/global.env
```

and rename `global.env` to `.env` and make sure it is on the same level as your compose file.

There is no such top-level attribute as `env_file` for docker-compose. `env_file` is a service level attribute.

Comment: Thanks bro. This is the [original repo](https://github.com/mayflower/postgraphile-example/blob/main/docker-compose.yml) for `docker-compose.yml`. I thought that I could join `db` and `migration` services into one as shown in the file above but I'm getting the following error on the log of `db_migration`: "psql: error:connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused. Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections? connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address" Is there a change I need to do?